# create html-table with php content

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a mysql database containing information about movies and at which hour they play in the movie theater. Now, I'm pretty new to this and was wondering what is the best way to make a html table with the content from the database, something like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="5">Programma</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="opacity:1">MovieName</td>
            <td>14u00</td>
            <td>17u00</td>
            <td>20u00</td>
            <td>22u30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="opacity:1">MovieName</td>
            <td>14u00</td>
            <td>17u00</td>
            <td>20u00</td>
            <td>22u30</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the cells containing the hours to only be visible if that hour is in the database. I know how to make a connection with the database but I'm not sure where to implement the php code and how to make the cells only visible when they are mentioned in the database for that movie. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you save data in your tables.
I assume you have two tables called "movies" and "showtimes"

```
movies
=============
id | movie
-------------
1  | Movie 1
2  | Movie 2
3  | Movie 3
___________________________________

showtimes
===================================
id | movie_id | showtime
-----------------------------------
1  | 1        | 9.00 am - 12 pm 
2  | 2        | 12.00 pm - 3 pm
3  | 1        | 3.00 pm - 6 pm
4  | 2        | 6.00 am - 9.00 pm
5  | 1        | 9.00 am - 12.00 am
___________________________________
```

```
  $sql = 'SELECT m.movie, group_concat(s.showtime) FROM movies m left join showtimes s on m.id=s.movie_id group by m.movie';
  $rs = mysql_query($rs);
  if($rs){

echo '<table>
       <thead>
          <tr><th colspan="5">Programma</th></tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>';

 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
      echo '<tr>
            <td style="opacity:1">'.$row->movie.'</td>';

      $showtimes = explode(',', $row->showtime);
      if($showtimes) {
         foreach($showtimes as $showtime) {    
             echo '<td>'.$showtime.'</td>';
         }
      }
      echo '</tr>';    
 }

 echo '</tbody>
       </table>';
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try using the foreach loop and inside it creating a new table row for each record and a table column for each attribute in the record

```
foreach($resultset as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how will I be able to control the visibility of the hourscheme then?

Comment: you can iterate over the table as and check with the database resultset for the existing hours. if they match show them, else don't print them... i hope you get what i am trying to tell.

Comment: hmm yes i think so, although I thought there would be another way because this is going to be pretty long code for something fairly easy, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: nope.. its not going to be long, just a loop and a table structure and a condition, that's all you will need.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use a nested foreach, will work for any two dimensional array

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $fieldName=>$field){
        echo "<td>",$field, "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```